# Using C#, how do I retrieve SAS token for account key to access (read/write/delete, etc..) blob storage?

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, access-keys, sas-token

[image]

How do I rewrite this code used for User delegation to account key?

```
 public async Task<string> GetBlobSASToken(string containerName)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Initial Load Worker called Blob SAS Token creation.");
        try
        {
            DbConnectionStringBuilder dbConnectionStringBuilder = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
            dbConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString = _config.BlobStorageConnectionString;

            var azureStorageAccount = dbConnectionStringBuilder["AccountName"].ToString();
            var azureStorageAccessKey = dbConnectionStringBuilder["AccountKey"].ToString();

            Azure.Storage.Sas.BlobSasBuilder blobSasBuilder = new Azure.Storage.Sas.BlobSasBuilder()
            {
                BlobContainerName = containerName,
                Protocol = SasProtocol.Https,
                Resource = "c",
                StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(-1),
                ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(3),
                  
            };
            blobSasBuilder.SetPermissions(
                Azure.Storage.Sas.BlobSasPermissions.Read |
                Azure.Storage.Sas.BlobSasPermissions.Add |
                Azure.Storage.Sas.BlobSasPermissions.Create |
                Azure.Storage.Sas.BlobSasPermissions.Write |
                Azure.Storage.Sas.BlobSasPermissions.Delete |
                Azure.Storage.Sas.BlobSasPermissions.List |
                Azure.Storage.Sas.BlobSasPermissions.SetImmutabilityPolicy
                );

            var sasToken = blobSasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(new StorageSharedKeyCredential(azureStorageAccount,
                azureStorageAccessKey)).ToString();

            return sasToken;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, $"Inital Load Worker has error when creating a SAS token for Initial Load Worker.");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, I can't use user delegation:

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You are using account key to generate SAS URL in your code.

Comment: If you look at the first image and look at the highlighted block in yellow. Depending what you pick, a different type of token is created via azure manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using C#, how do I retrieve the SAS token for the account key to access (read/write/delete, etc..) blob storage

You can follow this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas) to create a blob sas token using the account key.

You can use the below code to create a blob sas token with an account key using C#.

**Code:**

```
using Azure.Storage;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Sas;
namespace SAStoken
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var AccountName = "venkat123";
            var AccountKey = "<Your-account-key>";
            var containerName = "test";
            var blobName = "flatted.jpg";
            StorageSharedKeyCredential key = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(AccountName, AccountKey);
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri($"https://{AccountName}.blob.core.windows.net"), key);
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

            var sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
            {
                BlobContainerName = containerName,
                BlobName = blobName,
                Resource = "b", // b for blob, c for container
                StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(4),
            };
            sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.All); // All permissions like(Read,write,add,list,create,SetImmutabilityPolicy,delete)
            var Sas = sasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(key).ToString();
            var sasuri = blobClient.Uri.AbsoluteUri + "?" + Sas;
            Console.WriteLine(sasuri);
        }

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test/flatted.jpg?sv=2021-10-04&st=2023-05-13T05%3A00%3A38Z&se=2023-05-13T09%3A00%3A38Z&sr=b&sp=racwdxyltmei&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

[image]

**Browser:**
[image]

If you need to create a SAS token using user-delegation you need "**`Storage blob data contributor role`**".

Comment: I was a little confused on terminology and what I needed, but this code was perfect. It resolved my issue. Thank you so much!!!!